# Outputting Sound to Multiple Audio Devices Simultaneously

Tags: windows, audio, openal, simultaneous, directsound

OK, the first issue.  I am trying to write a virtual soundboard that will output to multiple devices at once.  I would prefer OpenAL for this, but if I have to switch over to MS libs (I'm writing this initially on Windows 7) I will.

Anyway, the idea is that you have a bunch of sound files loaded up and ready to play.  You're on Skype, and someone fails in a major way, so you hit the play button on the Price is Right fail ditty.  Both you and your friends hear this sound at the same time, and have a good laugh about it.

I've gotten OAL to the point where I can play on the default device, and selecting a device at this point seems rather trivial.  However, from what I understand, each OAL device needs its context to be current in order for the buffer to populate/propagate properly.  Which means, in a standard program, the sound would play on one device, and then the device would be switched and the sound buffered then played on the second device.

Is this possible at all, with any audio library?  Would threads be involved, and would those be safe?

Then, the next problem is, in order for it to integrate seamlessly with end-user setups, it would need to be able to either output to the default recording device, or intercept the recording device, mix it with the sound, and output it as another playback device.  Is either of these possible, and if both are, which is more feasible?  I think it would be preferable to be able to output to the recording device itself, as then the program wouldn't have to be running in order to have the microphone still work for calls.

Comment: Also, I don't even know where this posted, let alone if it posted correctly.  If it's not in the right place, I would appreciate it being moved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood well there are two questions here, mainly.

1. Is it possible to play a sound on two or more audio output devices simultaneously, and how to achieve this?
2. Is it possible to loop back data through a audio input (recording) device so that is is played on the respective monitor i.e for example sent through the audio stream of Skype to your partner, in your respective case.

**Answer to 1:** This is absolutely feasable, all independent audio outputs of your system can play sounds simultaneously. For example some professional audio interfaces (for music production) have 8, 16, 64 independent outputs of which all can be played sound simultaneously. That means that each output device maintains its own buffer that it consumes independently (apart from concurrency on eventual shared memory to feed the buffer).

**How?**

Most audio frameworks / systems provide functions to get a "device handle" which will need you to pass a callback for feeding the buffer with samples (so does Open AL for example). This will be called independently and asynchroneously by the framework / system (ultimately the audio device driver(s)). 
Since this all works asynchroneously you dont necessarily need multi-threading here. All you need to do in principle is maintaining two (or more) audio output device handles, each with a seperate buffer consuming callback, to feed the two (or more) seperate devices.

**Note** You can also play several sounds on one single device. Most devices / systems allow this kind of "resources sharing". Actually, that is one purpose for which sound cards are actually made for. To mix together all the sounds produced by the various programs (and hence take off that heavy burden from the CPU). When you use one (physical) device to play several sounds, the concept is the same as with multiple device. For each sound you get a logical device handle. Only that those handle refers to several "channels" of one physical device.

*What should you use?*

Open AL seems a little like using heavy artillery for this simple task I would say (since you dont want *that* much portability, and probably dont plan to implement your own codec and effects ;) )

I would recommend you to use Qt here. It is highly portable (Win/Mac/Linux) and it has a very handy class that will do the job for you: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudiooutput.html

Check the example in the documentation to see how to play a WAV file, with a couple of lines of code. To play several WAV files simultaneously you simply have to open several QAudioOutput (basically put the code from the example in a function and call it as often as you want). Note that you have to close / stop the QAudioOutput in order for the sound to stop playing.

**Answer to 2:** What you want to do is called a loopback. Only a very limited number of sound cards i.e audio devices provide a so called loopback input device, which would permit for recording what is currently output by the main output mix of the soundcard for example. However, even this kind of device provided, it will not permit you to loop back anything into the microphone input device. The microphone input device only takes data from the microphone D/A converter. This is deep in the H/W, you can not mix in anything on your level there.

This said, it will be very very hard (IMHO practicably impossible) to have Skype send your sound with a standard setup to your conversation partner. Only thing I can think of would be having an audio device with loopback capabilities (or simply have a physical cable connection a possible monitor line out to any recording line in), and have then Skype set up to use this looped back device as an input. However, Skype will not pick up from your microphone anymore, hence, you wont have a conversation ;)

**Note:** When saying "simultaneous" playback here, we are talking about synchronizing the playback of two sounds as concerned by real-time perception (in the range of 10-20ms). We are not looking at actual synchronization on a sample level, and the related clock jitter and phase shifting issues that come into play when sending sound onto two physical devices with two independent (free running) clocks. Thus, when the application demands in phase signal generation on independent devices, clock recovery mechanisms are necessary, which may be provided by the drivers or OS.

**Note:** Virtual audio device software such as Virtual Audio Cable will provide virtual devices to achieve loopback functionnality in Windows. Frameworks such as Jack Audio may achieve the same in UX environment.

Comment: One enormous caveat to doing this and that is synchronisation.  If the OP doesn't care about the outputs being synchronous, the approach above will work just fine.  If on the other hand, it's a requirement, this problem gets much, much harder as it is necessary to account for buffer delays to each output.

Comment: I disagree. First off what kind of delay do you mean? IMHO all you need to do is *count* buffers and add i.e mix them accordingly. Either by passing them to the seperate hardware buffers or by adding them up in software (summing of values and appropriated weighting to avoid distortion).

Comment: Obviously the *precise* way to synchronize is the second one (summing in software). I agree that you can not make sure that your hardware buffers are "in phase". However this difference is in the range of such low phase angles that you will only realize it in professional audio applications such as signal generators.

Comment: Well, I suppose I'm not surprised about outputting to a microphone.  Virtual Audio Cable is a program I've used capable of capturing two output devices, mixing them, and putting them on a custom loopback "device" that Skype can then pick up, but it needs to be running in order for it to work at all, and then you have to keep switching your default input device all the time.  I was hoping this wouldn't be necessary so that I could actually commercialize this program, but I guess operating systems just aren't meant to handle that sort of thing easily.  I appreciate the info.

Comment: @StephanHesse: You're not accounting for the fact that each individual audio interface has its own sample output clock.  Particularly if they are USB interfaces - where the clock is either free-running or rather imprecisely recovered from the isochronous rate of the bus - by necessity because of the lack of accurate timing reference.  You can get in theory get this to work with IEEE1394 audio interfaces as there is well defined model of the presentation time and proper clock recovery.   At the crudest level, you need to compensate for buffer latency on each output device.

Comment: @Malkierian You might be interested to know that MacOSX does (and has for quite some time) supported audio IO device aggregation and takes care of the timing issues as far as is possible - Apple has the luxury of providing most of the drivers itself and tightly defining the requirements for those it doesn't produce.

Comment: @marko Yes agreed, on seperate physical interfaces we will have real clock jitter and phase shifting issues. However the question is to figure out at what level of synchronization this really becomes a problem for the application. In the use-case sketched by the OP this does not play a role apparently. I added a note to make clear we are not adressing jitter and phase shift issues in between devices here, but only "simultaneous" playback, i.e synchronization of sounds, not necessarily on the sample level.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very easy way to output audio on two devices at the same time:

1. For Realtek devices you can use the Audio-mixer "trick" (but this will give you a delay / echo);
2. For everything else (and without echo) you can use Voicemeeter (which is totaly free).

I have explained BOTH solutions in this video: https://youtu.be/lpvae_2WOSQ

Best Regards

Comment: It would be better to explain it all in the text, no need for external Youtube links.